# Javascript: Can‘t get document.getelementbyid to work

Tags: javascript

I found many questions concerning form elements that are null but I simply can‘t get this to work.

It works in every browser but when it‘s embedded in Wordpress it stops working in Firefox.
The Firefox-Console says I should use document.getelementbyid but in every way I try it, Firefox says the form is null or that "myform is not defined".

Comment: It'll be easier to debug if you show is the version that ISN'T working, as opposed to the one that is.

Comment: @hunter: the link to dropbox has his code. @Philipp: Please explain what the problem is. Is it just the message? "It stops working" is not very helpful, specially when you didn't specify what working means...

Comment: I just fixed with Spidys help. Thanks a lot anyways! You guys are fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the html and javascript code? my first guess is that you didn't give the form or input an id attribute. For example

`<input name="myInput" type="text" />`

will not work for

`document.getElementById("myInput").`

You need to add the id attribute like so

```
<input id="myInput" name="myInput" type="text" />
```

Comment: Wow! That was the proplem. I simply put the name tag and not the id tag, by adding the id tag, everything works fine now! Thanks a lot for this fast reply, I should‘ve asked earlier. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue on firefox with a login script I wrote. Such a bugger to find when it works on Chrome and IE

Answer (score 2):

Your script uses `myform` as a global variable. Don't do that, that was an early hack from Internet Explorer, that created global variables for all elements with id/names and is currently frowned upon.

That's what the error message on Firefox tells you.

"Element referenced by ID/NAME in the global scope. Use W3C standard document.getElementById() instead.
`var userInputs = myform.elements; (rechner.html.22)`

Add the following to the top of your calculate function

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myform')
```

And change your form tag to be:

```
 <form name="myform" id="myform" action="#">
```

If this is not the issue at hand, please make your question more descriptive!

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you as well. This page is more than awesome, a seamless and great way to get help. I‘ll try to give something back now…

Answer (score 0):

Try using different ID, maybe total already exists in wordpress theme.
Can you please show this embeded in wordpress? It would be quite easier to debug.